# Asymptotic formula of $\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{r-1}}{(r-1)!}{n\choose r}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, summation, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

> I need to find the asymptotic equivalence of the sum $$\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{r-1}}{(r-1)!} 
> {n\choose r} $$ where ${n\choose r}$ is the binomial coefficient.

We have the binomial identity $$(1-x)^n=\sum_{r=0}^{n}(-1)^rx^r {n\choose r} $$
But how do we get $(r-1)!$ in the denominator? I am sorry that I am not able to think much about the problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{r-1}}{(r-1)!} 
{n\choose r}= L_{n - 1}^{(1)} (1) & = \sqrt {\frac{\mathrm{e}}{\pi }} (n - 1)^{1/4} \sin \left( {2\sqrt {n - 1}  - \frac{\pi }{4}} \right) + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^{1/4} }}} \right) \\ & = \sqrt {\frac{\mathrm{e}}{\pi }} n^{1/4} \sin \left( {2\sqrt n  - \frac{\pi }{4}} \right) + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^{1/4} }}} \right),
\end{align*}
where $L_n^{(\alpha)}(x)$ is the generalized Laguerre polynomial. See [this](https://doi.org/10.1137%2F07068031X) paper for the asymptotics of these polynomials. See also [here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/18.15.iv).

Comment: Thanks. But please give a detailed answer. I cannot understand how my sum is equal to $L_{n-1}^{(1)}(1)$?

Comment: It is because $$
L_n^{(\alpha )} (x) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {( - 1)^k \binom{n + \alpha}{k + \alpha} \frac{{x^k }}{{k!}}} .
$$ Have you tried looking up the generalized Laguerre polynomials?

Comment: +1. Thank you. Please give me a begginer reference to read about Laguerre polynomials

Comment: You can try the classical book *Orthogonal Polynomials* by Gábor Szegő. Also, if you are satisfied with my answer, you can accept it.

Comment: Accepted the answer. Thanks.